# iPhone Mute Switch Position From Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, uiwebview

Question is pretty self explanatory. Is it possible to read the position of the iPhone's mute switch from JavaScript running in a UIWebView/Safari? I haven't seen anything, so I'm going to assume there isn't any way to do this.

I know it's possible natively, so a using the JS-bridge techniques I could determine the value from native code and then hand it back to the JS, but it'd be nice to not have to muddle with that.

Comment: have you solved this problem?